# How to show a Game Center Achievement Notification

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

Is there a built in way to show a user a notification that they've earned a Game Center achievement?  Similar to the notification that appears when they are authenticated?

I was surprised when I completed my achievement and did not see a notification in my game.

Thanks!

Comment: Actually I never saw this in any game either. Only custom notifications.

Answer (score 12):

in iOS 5.0+ you can use

```
[GKNotificationbanner showBannerWithTitle:@"Title" message:@"Message" completionHandler:nil];
```

Comment: You sure can!  Back when I posted this question, iOS 4 was still widely used, and I wanted a solution that supported 4.x

Thanks for updating

Comment: I couldn't find a way to get the achievement name to show it. I ended up using: achievement.showsCompletionBanner = YES;